# When are these quotient rings isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-b).$ For which
>   $\mathbb{Z} \ni a, b$ it's true?

My first thought was: when $a = n^2, b = m^2$, where  $\mathbb{Z}\ni n, m.$ But i'm not sure that's an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pedestrian approach: let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Assume that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a)\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-b)$. This means that there is a ring isomorphism,
$$\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a)\to\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-b).$$
I guess we're working with unital rings, so must have $\varphi(1)=1$. Also, there exists $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi(x)=p+qx$. Then:
$$a=\varphi(a)=\varphi(x^2)=\varphi(x)^2=(p+qx)^2=(p^2+bq^2)+2pqx$$
from which we conclude:
$$\begin{cases}p^2+bq^2=a\\2pq=0.\end{cases}$$
We must have $q\neq0$ for otherwise $\varphi$ isn't surjective, hence from the second line, we must have $p=0$, and from the first line we conclude that $bq^2=a$.

Similarly, there exists $q'\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(x)=q'x$ and $q'$ satisfies: $a(q')^2=b$.

Hence, $a=bq^2=a(qq')^2$ from which we conclude that: either $a=0$ (and then $b=0$) or $q^2(q')^2=1$ and hence $q^2=1$ and hence $a=b$.

Conclusion: the two are isomorphic if and only if $a=b$, in which case there are exactly two isomorphisms!

Comment: Why $\varphi(x^2)$ is $\varphi(a)$? I don't understand how do you interpret this quotient ring. Cause I thought, that it contains classes $f+(x^2-a)$, where $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x] $, and $(x^2-a)$ is ideal of $ \mathbb{Z}[x] $

Comment: @Khan: Using the long division, every element $f$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be uniquely written as $f=\alpha x+\beta+(x^2-a)Q$, where $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I can then identify the class of $f$ with $\alpha x+\beta$. With this identification, it's very simple to work with $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a)$: you add and multiply terms as usual, and replace all the $x^2$ terms by $a$. For example, $$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=x^3+6x^2+11x+6=(11+a)x+(6+6a).$$ The justification of this is given by the long division.

Comment: @Khan: then $\varphi(x^2)=\varphi(a)=a\varphi(1)=a$ comes naturally.

Comment: I can replace $x^2$ by $a$, because i take $x^2 = x^2 + 0$, where 0 is zero ideal and then $x^2-a = 0$?

Comment: @Khan: how about we adopt a common notation: for $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we write $[Q]=Q+(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The term $(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by $x^2-a$. Then, $[P]=[Q]$ if and only if $P-Q\in(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]$, i.e., if and only if $P-Q$ is divisible by $x^2-a$. We'll write an element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a)$ as $[f]$, where $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then: $$[x^2]=x^2+(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]=a+(x^2-a)+(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]=a+(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]=[a].$$ I used: $(x^2-a)+(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]=(x^2-a)\bigl(1+\mathbb{Z}[x]\bigr)=(x^2-a)\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Now that's clear to me! Thank you.